# something wrong in this j query

Tags: jquery

```
function dowork()
{
    $(".wrappedElement").removeClass("wrappedElement");
    $(".wrappedElementout").removeClass("wrappedElementout");
    var a=$("div#DepPart select option:selected").val();

    $("div#TestPart select option[value^=a]").addClass("wrappedElement");
    $("div#TestPart select option[value!=a]:not(div#TestPart select option[value^=a])").addClass("wrappedElementout");
}
```

In this function var a gets the value (a="HMT") in string format and when i uses this value as part of the jQuery selector it does't work for some reason. Can anybody suggest what the solution may be?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: sorry pekka but it a jquery and i didn't get any error

Comment: @user1023160 - If you don't get an error message, then perhaps a problem description that says "I don't get any error messages, but I expected _this_ to happen and instead _that_ happened."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not referencing the variable `a` anywhere, you are simply including the letter "a" in your string. You need to concatenate the value from the variable `a` with the string you are using as a selector:

```
$("div#TestPart select option[value^='" + a + "']").addClass("wrappedElement");
$("div#TestPart select option[value!='" + a + "']:not(div#TestPart select option[value^='" + a + "'])").addClass("wrappedElementout");
```

Note also that jQuery selectors with the square bracket attribute equals *something* syntax expects the *something* to be in quotes (which I've included above).

With your example value of `a`, "HMT" the first selector will end up looking like the following after the concatenation:

```
"div#TestPart select option[value^='HMT']"
```

(And similar for the other line.)

Answer (score 1):

```
function dowork()
    {
    $(".wrappedElement").removeClass("wrappedElement");
    $(".wrappedElementout").removeClass("wrappedElementout");
    var a=$("div#DepPart select option:selected").val();

    $("div#TestPart select option[value^=" + a + "]").addClass("wrappedElement");
    $("div#TestPart select option[value!=" + a + "]:not(div#TestPart select option[value^="+ a + "])").addClass("wrappedElementout");
    }
```

Comment: i want to ask one more question from u regarding javascript or jquery

if i delete a row from table in a browser by jquery

and click on the submit button,then on the server side is this change reflect

Comment: it depends on what was on that deleted row , but as answer of your question i say : "Generally yes"

Answer (score 0):

You're using `a` as part of a string literal, i.e. it's being interpreted as the character 'a', not as the value of the variable `a`.

You need to take `a` out of the double quotes:

```
$("div#TestPart select option[value^=" + a + "]").addClass("wrappedElement");
    $("div#TestPart select option[value!=" + a + "]:not(div#TestPart select option[value^=" + a + "])").addClass("wrappedElementout");
```

Comment: i want to ask one more question from u regarding javascript or jquery

if i delete a row from table in a browser by jquery

and click on the submit button,then on the server side is this change reflect

Comment: You'd need to provide more information about what platform you're using etc. to get help with that!

Comment: I work on asp.net 2008 and i have a gridview, where I have a button field and on the click of this button, I want to remove that row from the grid view and when i click on submit, then only that rows which are left in the browser are to be saved on database